# Adding up the values of multiples fields then inserting in a MySQl column in php

Tags: php, mysql, session, variables, mysqli

I have a multi-page survey form that I have built in PHP and MySQL. Each page asks the user to chose a number between 1 and 10 at the end of the survey it inserts the data into a MySQl database.

What I need to do it create an additional column that adds up the values of all 2 fields and inserts it into the total_score field.

I am a bit stuck if anymore can point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

My code is below:

```
    <?php
session_start(); // Session starts here.
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$_SESSION['answer_20'] = $_POST['answer_20'];

$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
$gender = $_SESSION['gender'];
$postcode = $_SESSION['postcode'];
$ethnicity = $_SESSION['ethnicity'] ;
$lbote = $_SESSION['lbote'];
$atsi = $_SESSION['atsi'];
$numberofchildreninncare = $_SESSION['numberofchildreninncare'] ;
$youngestchild = $_SESSION['youngestchild'];
$ifother = $_SESSION['ifother'];
$eldestchild = $_SESSION['eldestchild'];
$ageofchild = $_SESSION['ageofchild'];
$relationship = $_SESSION['relationship'];
$education = $_SESSION['education'];
$liveshome = $_SESSION['liveshome'];

$answer_01 = $_SESSION['answer_01'];
$answer_02 = $_SESSION['answer_02'];
$answer_03 = $_SESSION['answer_03'];
$answer_04 = $_SESSION['answer_04'];
$answer_05 = $_SESSION['answer_05'];
$answer_06 = $_SESSION['answer_06'];
$answer_07 = $_SESSION['answer_07'];
$answer_08 = $_SESSION['answer_08'];
$answer_09 = $_SESSION['answer_09'];
$answer_10 = $_SESSION['answer_10'];
$answer_11 = $_SESSION['answer_11'];
$answer_12 = $_SESSION['answer_12'];
$answer_13 = $_SESSION['answer_13'];
$answer_14 = $_SESSION['answer_14'];
$answer_15 = $_SESSION['answer_15'];
$answer_16 = $_SESSION['answer_16'];
$answer_17 = $_SESSION['answer_17'];
$answer_18 = $_SESSION['answer_18'];
$answer_19 = $_SESSION['answer_19'];
$answer_20 = $_SESSION['answer_20'];
$client_id = $_SESSION['client_id'];
$family_id = $_SESSION['family_id'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO results (firstname,lastname,gender,postcode,ethnicity,lbote,atsi,numberofchildreninncare,youngestchild,ageofchild,ifother,eldestchild,relationship,education,liveshome,answer_01,answer_02,answer_03,answer_04,answer_05,answer_06,answer_07,answer_08,answer_09,answer_10,answer_11,answer_12,answer_13,answer_14,answer_15,answer_16,answer_17,answer_18,answer_19,answer_20,client_id,family_id,parent_subscale,connect_subscale,total_score)

VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$gender','$postcode','$ethnicity','$lbote','$atsi','$numberofchildreninncare','$youngestchild','$ageofchild','$ifother','$eldestchild','$relationship','$education','$liveshome','$answer_01','$answer_02','$answer_03','$answer_04','$answer_05','$answer_06','$answer_07','$answer_08','$answer_09','$answer_10','$answer_11','$answer_12','$answer_13','$answer_14','$answer_15','$answer_16','$answer_17','$answer_18','$answer_19','$answer_20','$client_id','$family_id','$parent_subscale','$connect_subscale','$total_score')";

$today = date("d M Y");

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: which one you want addition (variable name ? ) ?

Comment: Hello, basically I want to add up the numbers/values of answer_01 through to answer_20 then insert int into total_score column

Comment: try my updated answer @Phil

Answer (score 0):

example  try something like this .i workout this its worked fine for me

```
<?php
session_start(); // Session starts here.
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

$_SESSION['answer_20'] = $_POST['answer_20'];

$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];
$gender = $_SESSION['gender'];
$postcode = $_SESSION['postcode'];
$ethnicity = $_SESSION['ethnicity'] ;
$lbote = $_SESSION['lbote'];
$atsi = $_SESSION['atsi'];
$numberofchildreninncare = $_SESSION['numberofchildreninncare'] ;
$youngestchild = $_SESSION['youngestchild'];
$ifother = $_SESSION['ifother'];
$eldestchild = $_SESSION['eldestchild'];
$ageofchild = $_SESSION['ageofchild'];
$relationship = $_SESSION['relationship'];
$education = $_SESSION['education'];
$liveshome = $_SESSION['liveshome'];


$client_id = $_SESSION['client_id'];
$family_id = $_SESSION['family_id'];



$total_score=0;
for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++)
{



if($i<10)
{

     $no = "0".$i; 

     $answer_.$no='';

    if(isset($_SESSION['answer_'. $no]))
    {
        $answer_.$no =$_SESSION['answer_'. $no];

        $total_score += $_SESSION['answer_'. $no];

    }


} 
else
{
     $answer_.$i='';

    if(isset($_SESSION['answer_'. $i]))
    {
        $answer_.$i =$_SESSION['answer_'. $i];

        $total_score += $_SESSION['answer_'. $i];

    }
}


}   

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO results (firstname,lastname,gender,postcode,ethnicity,lbote,atsi,numberofchildreninncare,youngestchild,ageofchild,ifother,eldestchild,relationship,education,liveshome,answer_01,answer_02,answer_03,answer_04,answer_05,answer_06,answer_07,answer_08,answer_09,answer_10,answer_11,answer_12,answer_13,answer_14,answer_15,answer_16,answer_17,answer_18,answer_19,answer_20,client_id,family_id,parent_subscale,connect_subscale,total_score)

    VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$gender','$postcode','$ethnicity','$lbote','$atsi','$numberofchildreninncare','$youngestchild','$ageofchild','$ifother','$eldestchild','$relationship','$education','$liveshome','$answer_01','$answer_02','$answer_03','$answer_04','$answer_05','$answer_06','$answer_07','$answer_08','$answer_09','$answer_10','$answer_11','$answer_12','$answer_13','$answer_14','$answer_15','$answer_16','$answer_17','$answer_18','$answer_19','$answer_20','$client_id','$family_id','$parent_subscale','$connect_subscale','$total_score')";

    $today = date("d M Y");

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Hi jothi thank you for your response that is great, my php isnt great, could you advise how I could add it into my code in my original post?

Comment: wait i will do for you

Comment: @ jothi thank you for that, but I am getting hte folloing errors on sumit 'Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent' and 'Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/username/public_html/folder/complete.php on line 44' any ideas?

Comment: find the php.ini file and increase the execution time

Comment: follow this https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/using-php.ini-directives/php-maximum-execution-time

Comment: max_execution_time = 90

Comment: "Headers already sent" means that your PHP script already sent the HTTP headers, and as such it can't make modifications to them now.

Check that you don't send ANY content before calling session_start. Better yet, just make session_start the first thing you do in your PHP file (so put it at the absolute beginning, before all HTML etc).

Comment: Great thanks jothi, I will do that. Thanks for your help. its much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113286/discussion-between-jothi-and-phil).

Comment: Hi jothi, thanks but I cant sort it out form here. thanks for your help.